# Gradle sync failed Invalid Project Jdk

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-import

Getting fed up with this problem, heard android studio is better than eclipse in many ways, but I cant even start a single project with it because of this error, tried many solutions still its showing same thing, First i thought it was only when importing old eclipse project, but its not.

1) I tried uninstalling every jdk and jre and installed latest **JDK 1.8.0_65** and set all paths and JAVA_HOME

```
C:\Users\username>java -version
java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)

C:\Users\username>javac -version
javac 1.8.0_65

C:\Users\username>set JAVA_HOME
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65
```

2) Reinstalled android studio

3) Updated all sdk using sdk manager

still if i try to start a new project, i am getting the error

```
8:10:45 PM Invalid Project JDK
           Please choose a valid JDK directory
           Open JDK Settings
8:10:45 PM Gradle sync started
8:10:45 PM Gradle sync failed: Invalid Project Jdk
```

JDK Location by default it is showing C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10, And i am changing it to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65, But seems like its not getting applied.
By the way, I am using 64 bit windows 7 and installed 64 bit java.Hope someone can guide me from this mess, its been few night am wasting time on this.

Adding screenshot of my JAVA_HOME
[image]

Below is the screenshot of JDK location that is showing inside android studio

[image]

Comment: are you sure java installed properly
Check with javac commnd

Comment: above you can see javac command i used ,it give output as below   C:\Users\username>javac -version
javac 1.8.0_65

Comment: why not just set jdk inside android studio?

Comment: Try `java -d64 -version`

Comment: @user4847410 Tried and i got below output C:\Users\username>java -d64 -version
java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio 1.5.1, this error was shown in red: "Android SDK location should not contain whitespace, as this can cause problems with the NDK tools." The problem was never with the JDK location. It was with the SDK Location.

I moved the SDK folder out of `Program Files` because of the whitespace, changed `D:\Program Files\Android\sdk` to `D:\Android\sdk`, and the JDK location then stayed. Android Studio does not seem to like saving the JDK location value if there is an error with the SDK location.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Don't use cmd line, just do it normally.

[image: do you check here?]

[image]

if you use a error path, it will warn you .

Comment: Thank you for reply, same i already done, please see the screenshot

Comment: Added screenshot for the same, there it is showing another version of java which i uninstalled, there is no such folder and when i edit it and change it to the new JDK location , its not getting applied.

Comment: Yes, but no result, i resolved the issue by reinstalling both android studio and JDK.Thank you

Answer (score -2):

go to your

> C:\programFiles\Java

copy your Java folder
then go to your

> C:\programFiles(x86)

paste the files there.
then go back to your androidstudio change your JDK directory to this

> C:\programFiles(x86)\java\jdk1.8.0_74.

"mine is jdk1.8.074 yours might be different, put whatever yours is"